# How do I change the font size in Conky?

Tags: conky

I was wondering how to change the size of ALL the fonts to a bigger size.
Also under cpu usage I have 2 numbers one is white like U want it and the other is green and I can't figure out how to change just that one to white.
I have pasted my conkyrc if that helps.
I am sure its easy but for some reason I just cant seem to get it.
And always TYAVMIA :-)

```
background yes 
font Liberation:size=9 
xftfont Sans Seriff:size=9 
use_xft yes 
xftalpha 0.1 
update_interval 4.0 
total_run_times 0 
own_window yes 
own_window_type override 
own_window_transparent yes 
own_window_hints undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager 
double_buffer yes 
draw_shades no 
draw_outline no 
draw_borders no 
draw_graph_borders no 
minimum_size 620 
maximum_width 420 
default_color ffff00 
default_shade_color 000000 
default_outline_color 000000 
alignment top_right 
gap_x 6 
gap_y 22 
no_buffers yes 
cpu_avg_samples 2 
override_utf8_locale no 
uppercase no # set to yes if you want all text to be in uppercase 
use_spacer no 

TEXT 

${color #ffffff}${font Liberation:style=Bold:pixelsize=12}SYSTEM:${hr 1 } 
${color white}O/S: ${color #ffff00}${alignr}Ubuntu 10.10 
${color white}O/S architecture: ${color #ffff00}${alignr}64 Bit 
${color white}Hostname: ${color #ffff00}$alignr$nodename 
${color white}Kernel: ${color #ffff00}$alignr$kernel 
${color white}Uptime: ${color #ffff00}$alignr$uptime 
${color white}Processes: ${color #ffff00}${alignr}$processes ($running_processes running) 
${color white}Load: ${color #ffff00}${alignr}$loadavg 
${color white}${font Liberation:style=Bold:pixelsize=12}CPU: ${hr 1 } 
${color white}Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU E5200 @ 2.50GHz 
${color white}CPU Usage: ${color white}${alignr} ${freq}MHz X 2 ${color white} 
${cpu cpu1}% ${color #00ff00} ${alignr}${cpubar cpu1 3,170} 
${cpu cpu2}% ${color #00ff00} ${alignr}${cpubar cpu2 3,170} 
${color white}${font Liberation:style=Bold:pixelsize=12}${hr 1}${color #cccccc} 
${color white}Cores: 
${color white}${cpu cpu1}% ${color #00ff00}${alignr}${cpubar cpu1 3,170} 
${color white}${cpu cpu2}% ${color #00ff00}${alignr}${cpubar cpu2 3,170} 
${color #ffffff}${font Liberation:style=Bold:pixelsize=12 
${color white}${cpu cpu1}% ${color #00ff00}${alignr}${cpubar cpu1 3,170} 
${color white}${cpu cpu2}% ${color #00ff00}${alignr}${cpubar cpu2 3,170} 
${color #ffffff}${font Liberation:style=Bold:pixelsize=12}RAM:${hr 1 }${color #ffff00} 
${alignr}$mem / $memmax ($memperc%)${color #ffff00} 
${color #00ff00}${membar 3} 
${color white}Swap: ${color #ffff00}${alignr}$swap/$swapmax 
${color #00ff00}${swapbar 3} 
${color white}${font Liberation:style=Bold:pixelsize=12}${font pixelsize=20}${alignc}Time: ${time %I : %M : %S %P } 
${color #ffffff}${font Liberation:style=Bold:pixelsize=12}HIGHEST CPU $alignr CPU% MEM% 
${hr 1} 
${color white}${top name 1}${color #ffff00}$alignr${top cpu 1}${top mem 1} 
${color white}${top name 2}${color #ffff00}$alignr${top cpu 2}${top mem 2} 
${color #ffffff}${font Liberation:style=Bold:pixelsize=12}${hr 1} 
HIGHEST MEM $alignr CPU% MEM% 
${hr 1} 
${color white}${top_mem name 1}${color white}$alignr${top_mem cpu 1}${top_mem mem 1} 
${color white}${top_mem name 2}$alignr${color white}${top_mem cpu 2}${top_mem mem 2} 
${color #ffffff}${font Liberation:style=Bold:pixelsize=12}DISK I/O: ${diskio} 
${color #00ff00}${diskiograph /dev/sda 3,170} 
${color #ffffff}${font Liberation:style=Bold:pixelsize=12}FILESYSTEM ${hr 1} 
${color white}Root: ${color #ffff00}${alignr}${fs_free /} / ${fs_size /} 
${color #00ff00}${fs_bar 3 /} 
${color white}New Volume: ${color #ffff00}${alignr}${fs_free /media/New Volume} / ${fs_size /media/New Volume} 
${color #00ff00}${fs_bar 3 /media/New Volume} 
${color #ffffff}${font Liberation:style=Bold:pixelsize=12}NETWORK:${hr 1} 
${color white}IP: ${color #ffff00}${addr eth0} /
```

Comment: Please [edit] this question to change `U` to `you`, `cant` to `can't`, completely remove the irrelevant `And always TYAVMIA :-)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wherever is says `pixelsize=12`, change the `12` to whatever font size you want.

To change the color for the second cpu usage number, append `${color white}`  to the line
`${cpu cpu2}% ${color #00ff00} ${alignr}${cpubar cpu2 3,170}`:

`${color white}${cpu cpu2}% ${color #00ff00} ${alignr}${cpubar cpu2 3,170}`

[image]

Comment: Thank you so very much. The people i have run into with Ubuntu are MORE than helpful. I hope i can help with something someday TYAVM :-)

Comment: @DonaldDornJr Don't forget to click the green checkmark and up vote ;)